# Are there any grammatical errors in this sentence?

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning, grammaticality, error

Actually I'm an English learner and always try to write small lines. I wrote this (maybe you already read it somewhere but I didn't). Are there any errors or wrong words used in this line?

> "Everybody knows life is one time opportunity but only few realize."

If there are, could you please correct and give some suggestion to make it a better line?

Answer (score 1):

**Original Statement:** "Everybody knows life is one time opportunity but only few realize."

The sentence does have a slightly foreign flavor because it is missing some of the words that native speakers would include. But the meaning of the sentence is puzzling too, so that it’s hard to know how to improve it. If you wrote the sentence, maybe you can explain its meaning to help us reword it properly.

**Paraphrase A:** “Everybody knows that life is a one-time opportunity, but only a few people realize that it is."

In my opinion, Paraphrase A sounds like native speech. But what does it mean? It is hard to see how everybody could know a fact which only a few people realize. Knowing a fact and realizing that fact are very close to the same thing. So while Paraphrase A sounds like native speech, I doubt that it expresses your meaning correctly.

**Paraphrase B:** “Everybody knows that life is a one-time opportunity, but few people realize it."

Did you mean that few people realize the opportunity (rather than realizing the fact that life is an opportunity)? If that’s what you meant, I would say this sentence is a cleverly worded observation about life that might be lost on some readers. But such is life. Paraphrase B sounds (to me) like native speech, and it preserves the [ambiguity](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/realize) that you might have intended, so that “realize it” might refer to realizing the fact that life is an opportunity, or realizing (making actual) the opportunity which life represents.

By the way, you said that you try to write small lines. If I explained this small line correctly in the paragraph before this one, could I suggest that by "small lines" you mean [epigrams](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/epigram)?

Comment: Tried to write like an epigram. Paraphrase B is what I thought about! Thank you very much for explaining. You're really a good human. Good humans - better world.